# How to join to left join two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have two tables tableCode and tableName as below:

```
tableCode
code1, code2, code3, name3
1,     1,     1,     code31name

tableName
type, typeName, code, name
c1,       code1,        1,    code11name
c2,       code2,        1,    code21name
```

I want to select result as below

```
1,code11name,1,code21name,1,code31name
```

I only know as below, can you help me?

```
select m1.code1, m2.name, m1.code2, m3.name, m1.code3, m1.name3 
from tableCode m1 
left join tableName m2 on m1.code1 = m2.code and m2.type ='c1'
left join tableName m3 on m1.code1 = m3.code and m3.type ='c2'
```

Comment: Help you do what? What is the problem? What is your question? Please use words to explain what the output looks like based on the input. It is not clear from your example. PS Read about pivoting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I modified my sql, is it ok?

Comment: You are not explaining yourself. See my previous comment.

Comment: It looks like what you've got should return what you want.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your code has a `type` column, but none of your tables do.  I assume from your desired results that `tableName` has another row for `code3`.

Comment: By "type" I'm guessing that means "category". At least it should.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more join.  I think you are confused by your table aliases:

```
select c.code1, n1.name, c.code2, n2.name, c.code3, n3.name3 
from tableCode c left join
     tableName n1
     on n1.code = c.code1 and n1.category  = 'c1' left join
     tableName n2
     on n2.code = c.code2 and n2.category  = 'c2' left join
     tableName n3
     on n3.code = c.code3 and n3.category  = 'c3';
```